# Python Error: 5.7.0 must issue a starttls command first

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I try to send an email with my python script, but I got the error message:

```
5.7.0 must issue a starttls command first
```

I'm using `smtplib` and this is my code:

```
import smtplib

sender = 'from@fromdomain.com'
receivers = 'to@todomain.com'

message = """From: From Person <from@fromdomain.com>
To: To Person <to@todomain.com>
Subject: SMTP e-mail test

This is a test e-mail message.
"""

try:
    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com')
    smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)         
    print "Successfully sent email"
except Exception,e:
    print str(e)
```

If some one have an idea about how to solve this error I'll be grateful.

Comment: Gmail requires that you turn on encryption (start TLS) and authenticate before sending email.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GMail won't let random users send mail through their SMTP servers.

As the error says, you'll have to call [`SMTP.starttls`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.starttls) first and authenticate.